# Valuations at non-smooth points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the cuspidal cubic $X$ given by $y^2 = x^3$, and let $P$ denote the point at the origin. $V(x)$ cuts out $2P$ and some third point $E$ at infinity, and $V(y)$ cuts out $3P$.

I am wondering if there is a reasonable way to assign the divisor $P - E$ to $y/x$, even though the local ring at $P$ is not a discrete valuation ring (because if it was the Zariski tangent space would have dimension 1, but $P$ is a singular point on $X$.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very reasonable to assign to to the rational function $\frac yx$ on $X$ the divisor $1\cdot[P]-1\cdot [E]$.

The basic fact is that for a local noetherian domain $A$ of dimension $1$ and for a non zero element $0\neq a\in A$ we can define $\operatorname {ord }(a)=\operatorname {length }_A(A/aA)$ and extend this definition to the non-zero elements of the fraction field $K=\operatorname {Frac}(A)$ by $$\operatorname {ord }(a/b)=\operatorname {ord }(a)-\operatorname {ord }(b)$$ thus obtaining a group morphism $\operatorname {ord }:K^*\to \mathbb Z$.
If $A$ happens to be a discrete valuation ring this order function coincides with the  discrete valuation of the ring.
This allows us to define for a locally noetherian integral scheme a group morphism $$\operatorname {div}:\operatorname {Rat}(X)^*\to \operatorname {Wdiv}(X)$$ attaching a Weil divisor to any non-zero rational function
(Notice that Hartshorne only defines this morphism for schemes which are regular in codimension one.)
In your example we get, exactly as  you conjectured,  $$\operatorname {div}(\frac yx)=1\cdot[P]-1\cdot [E]$$
**Bibliography**
This is all very clearly explained in [Fulton's Intersction Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387985497) Chapter 1, 1.2 and 1.3 and Appendix A.3 .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Fulton's book is moving up on my list. Quick stupid question: In the smooth setting, checking the valuations is a useful way to check regularity of a function. (The statement of "algebraic Hartogs lemma" that I am familiar with is for integrally closed Noetherian domains.) Does a similar idea work here? In particular, on the affine path $X \setminus E$, can we conclude from the divisor calculation that $y/x$ is regular but $x/y$ is not? (Can we at least conclude that $y/x$ is in each local ring?) (I'm not at all sure that it should be.)